# Is it possible to dynamically retrieve the number of columns in a view in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

As the title says, is it possible to retrieve the number of columns in a view dynamically?

I'm learning Oracle 11gR2 and I'm checking out the V$ views. One of the things I want to do is output them to file (for various reasons I am unable to spool the document) so I was going to output using java, however I need to know how many columns are in each view - a daunting task with 536 views, and now I'm curious to if I can do this dynamically.

I tried using `user_tab_columns` but it returns 0 for views.

**Note**: performance is not key, this is a learning exercise for me, so doing it correctly is more important than doing it quickly (if its even possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spool the columns of the V$ views in Oracle you can use:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, column_id
from dba_tab_columns c
where table_name = 'V_$PARAMETER'
order by owner, table_name, column_id
```

Comment: That works well for some of the views, however V$SEGSTAT returns 0 cols, any idea why?

Comment: use V_$SEGSTAT v$segstat is only a synonym for V_$SEGSTAT

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression that the V_ views should be avoided in favor of V$. Does this convention hold true for the naming of all the views? (i.e. I want to run the code once, not run, correct any errors and run again etc)

Comment: Answered my own question - yes. Thanks for the help, the final query I used is `select count(column_name) from dba_tab_columns c WHERE table_name LIKE 'V_$HANG_SESSION_INFO'`, of course the view is replaced as required....